# Problems with displaying list items inline

Tags: css

I have been trying to get the links on [this webpage](http://www.shpe-uiuc.org) to be displayed `inline` using:

```
<style type="text/css">
ul#nav li.top {
 display:inline;
}
</style>
```

However, it only seems to work for *some* of the links even though they are all `li` elements with the `.top` class. If anybody could explain to me why this isn't working, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some tables inside of the `li`elements. Tables are block elements, they close the last inline box. Remove the tables or use `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please add the one properties in your css top class as like this .

```
.top{
display:inline-block;
}
```